# pyLDAvis prepare() is slow

Tags: python, gensim, lda

The code below takes forever to execute. Probably due to the large size of the dictionary. Is there a way to make it faster, by e.g. cropping the visualized data?

```
vis = pyLDAvis.gensim.prepare(lda, corpus, id2word)
```

Comment: I encounter the similar problem. Yet, the prepare call is very fast on my desktop, but so slow on my server -- which has only a single CPU. I suspect that the code is not optimized on less powerful machines.

Comment: @GangLiang From what I've learned, the problem is the default mds algorithm. See the answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the default mds algorithm (*pcoa*) is unstable. Using different algorithm (e.g. *mmds*) makes if faster:

```
vis = pyLDAvis.gensim.prepare(lda, corpus, id2word, mds='mmds')
pyLDAvis.show(vis)
```

Comment: It doesn't help at least in my case. On my desktop, I experimented to run the same code (a) on the system python3 installation, (b) inside a venv environment. the speed difference is strikingly slower inside venv. It finishes though: but takes a few minutes.